# Unable to get the object property

Tags: javascript, jquery, console.log

[image]

[image]

As in the image for an object which has _id property shown when checked in console as complete object
but it does not show its _id property when checked seperately in the console.log()

```
console.log(originalEventObject);
                                console.log(originalEventObject._id);
```

the object when seen inside the console gives me the values shown in the image 
but when I check the objects id i get the undefined in the console.log()
What is the proper way of fetching the _id from the object

```
(function($) {
    Drupal.fullcalendar.plugins.test_module = {
        options: function (fullcalendar, settings) {
            return {
                editable : true,
                droppable: true,
                dropAccept: '.ui-state-default',
                drop: function(date, allDay) {
                    if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                        $(this).draggable('disable');
                    }
                    alert("Dropped on " + date + " with allDay=" + allDay);
                    // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object                                                                     
                    var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
                    originalEventObject.start = date;
                    originalEventObject.allDay = allDay;
                    originalEventObject.backgroundColor = 'red';
                    // render the event on the calendar                                                                                       
                    var obj = $('.fullcalendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
                    var val_id = [] ;
                    $.map(obj,function(val) {
                            val_id.push(val._id);
                        });
                    $.map(obj,function(val) {
                            if (originalEventObject.title == val.title) {
                                val.end = originalEventObject.start;
                                $.extend(val, originalEventObject);
                                var eid = val.eid;
                                var start = val.start;
                                var end;
                                if (val.end == null) {
                                end = val.start;
                                }
                        else {
                                var end = val.end;
                                }
 }
                                $.post('?q=test-alter-appointment-ajax', { start: start.toString(), end: end.toString(), eid: eid}, function(\
) { alert(3);});

                                console.log(originalEventObject);
                                console.log(originalEventObject._id);
                                $('.fullcalendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', originalEventObject, true);
                                //$('.fullcalendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',originalEventObject._id);                                    

                            }
                        });
                }
            };
        },
    };



}(jQuery));
```

Comment: better make a fiddle and demonstrate your problem. :).

Comment: Please post your code :)

Comment: @harshal, we mean post all the relevant code you are using, not just the console calls, using an image like that to show your code is not helpful

Comment: it would be better if you add what the object looks like in console

Comment: pls check the image i have added the console values in it  @ChakradharVyza

Comment: @harshal did you try accessing it like `originalEventObject.id` ??

Comment: yes but it does not work also the prop name is itself '_id' so no chance it would work @ChakradharVyza